# Filter an array based on another array of numbers, however, if the array of number includes number 7, filter based on all numbers over 7

Tags: javascript

I'm making a website for an online card game and each card in this game has a cost. I have an array of 8 elements which contain MOST of the possible costs:

```
costs: [
    { cost: 0, active: true },
    { cost: 1, active: true },
    { cost: 2, active: true },
    { cost: 3, active: true },
    { cost: 4, active: true },
    { cost: 5, active: true },
    { cost: 6, active: true },
    { cost: 7, active: true }
],
```

Cost 0 to 7 covers most of the cards, however, there are a few exceptions which go over 7. Currently my filter function looks like this:

```
filteredByCost(cards){
    if (!this.costs) return cards

    let activeCosts = this.costs.filter((cost) => {
        return cost.active === true
    })

    let activeCostsStrings = activeCosts.map((activeCost) => {
        return activeCost.cost
    })

    let includesSevenCost = activeCostsStrings.includes(7)

    return cards.filter((card) => {
         return activeCostsStrings.includes(card.cost)
     })
},
```

First I find all active costs inside the costs array, then I make an array of numbers with the costs, and finally I filter the cards based on the array of numbers and returns an array of cards that have cost of 0 to 7. However, there are some cards that have cost > 7 so I'm trying to figure out how to return them as well when the array of numbers includes a 7.

```
let includesSevenCost = activeCostsStrings.includes(7)
```

This returns true if my array of numbers contain the number 7.

Example of a card that wouldn't get caught by my filter right now:

```
{
  "region": "Freljord",
  "attack": 0,
  "cost": 12,
  "health": 0,
}
```

Comment: do you have an example of this: "*However, there are some cards that have cost > 7 so I'm trying to figure out how to return them as well when the array of numbers includes a 7.*"

Comment: @NinaScholz I've included one of the card objects that have a cost that is higher than 7 which would not be returned by my filter right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add one more condition in filter function:

```
return cards.filter((card) => {
         return activeCostsStrings.includes(card.cost) || (card.cost > 7 && includesSevenCost)
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the maximum value `cost` of `costs` array and filter with this value.

```
var max = Math.max(...costs.map(({ cost }) => cost));

return cards.filter(({ cost }) => cost >= max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object or an array that contains an array of low cost object and an array of high cost objects.

Details are commented in demo

```js
const cards = [
  { cost: 0, active: true },
  { cost: 8, active: false },
  { cost: 3, active: true },
  { cost: 3, active: true },
  { cost: 1, active: true },
  { cost: 9, active: true },
  { cost: 6, active: false },
  { cost: 9, active: false },
  { cost: 8, active: true },
  { cost: 5, active: false },
  { cost: 2, active: true },
  { cost: 7, active: true },
  { cost: 1, active: false },
  { cost: 5, active: true },
  { cost: 3, active: true },
  { cost: 6, active: false },
  { cost: 4, active: true },
  { cost: 8, active: true },
  { cost: 8, active: false },
  { cost: 0, active: false },
  { cost: 8, active: false },
  { cost: 12, active: true },
  { cost: 5, active: true },
  { cost: 7, active: true },
];

// Pass in the array and a number that is considered high
const hiLow = (cardArray, high) => {

  // Filter the cards that are active
  const active = cardArray.filter(card => card.active);
  
  // Declare two empty arrays
  let low = [];
  let hi = [];
  
  // Iterate through the active array...
  for (let activeCard of active) {
  
    /*
    if the object cost is less than the high number...
    push the object to the low array
    Otherwise push the object to the hi array
    */
    if (activeCard.cost < high) {
      low.push(activeCard);
    } else {
      hi.push(activeCard);
    }
  }
  // return an object that has both arrays 
  return {low: low, high: hi};
}

console.log(hiLow(cards, 8));
```